# Exporting a scene from Blender into glft2.0 results in severe darkening of any textures using an alpha map?

Tags: textures, blender, alpha, gltf

I'm using blender 3.1.2, and I'm looking to export a model which is using a variety of typical texture maps. This all works fine on its own, exporting flawlessly into a .glb through Blender.

The issue arises when I try to use an alpha map, in this case made through Blender's Texture Paint tools, but the issue occurs even with a loaded alpha map. The transparency is perfect, but the value drops significantly inside the exported .glb file.

I just want to reiterate that the texture works as expected in a gltf while in isolation from the alpha map, and even with the alpha map present it appears as expected inside of Blender itself. The problem seems to be somewhere in exporting to the gltf format.

I've fiddled with it, but to no avail. If someone knows what's up, I could certainly use the help!

Comment: forgot to mention that I'm viewing the .glb with 3D Viewer, but the resulting darkening of the texture is consistent in other programs.

Comment: This definitely sounds like a bug, it might be worth reporting something at https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF-Blender-IO/ if you're able to share the `.blend` file! Blender will have to combine the alpha map and the base color map (if any) at export, so perhaps something is going wrong there.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone finds this and has the same problem, I did end up just taking the easy route, modifying the texture to compensate for the darkening. It works like I need it to, just was hoping to find a better way.